# Not able to create a table in MySQL Database in NetBeans 12.4

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to create a table in my database using NetBeans 12.4 but there's a syntax error every time I do it. I created a test table to ensure NetBeans is working fine, and the table was created successfully. I think there's some problem with my table specifically.
Please help. Here is the error

[SQL Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u91Qx.png)

And here is the SQL Table specs

[SQL Table Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0HBH.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

as @scheinwerfer mentioned, `from` is a reserved keyword in mysql. You may use reserved keywords if you quote them. You can check all mysql keywords here: [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-6-detailed-F)

Answer (score 0):

I think it´s because the name of you´re  variable. FROM is also a command in MySQL. Rename it and try again.